# String to number to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, numbers

I have a string `"215.00"`.

I want to convert this to a number and when I do `parseInt("215.00")` it returns 215 as a number. I want it to be as a number `215.00`.

To try and do this I did `parseFloat("215.00").toFixed(2);`, however this also returns a string. I have found many answers on here, but they all convert the number to a string. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Please see my code attempt below:

```
var number = "215.00";
parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
```

I want to get `215.00` as opposed to `"215.00"`

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string always

Comment: @ShintuJoseph so how can i do it so that it returns a number to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @phantom, may I ask you why do you need that? The numerical value of 215.00 is exactly 215, therefore it would make no difference.

Comment: If you want to use it for computations, missing the decimal zeros make no difference.If its for display purposes, the toFixed string should be rendered as required. So what's your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post here this as an Answer, for future purpose.

If you want to represent the zeros on the right hand-side, you need to represent it as a string. Because the numerical value of 215.00 it is in fact 215, therefore it will not keep the two decimal places.

The parseFloat method would work for a number such as "215.01", where it would parse it to the numerical value of 215.01.